# Quick structured text data lookup from command line?

Tags: shell, awk, data-structures, grep

Say I have a predictable text document structured with some IDs called `X:` and known combination of attributes, e.g. category `Y:` with a known number of instances (e.g. always only 1 `Y:` after each `X:` in the series):

```
  X:37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:BLUE
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
```

I want to retrieve the list of item IDs for all the blue things. I don't care if there are duplicate IDs or not, just which ID values are in the document. Then I want to sort the list and compare with the blue thing ID list from another structured text doc with the exact same structure ("which blue things are common to both docs?" "which blue things are in doc 1 but not in doc 2?").

I know I can `grep` for all the `Y:BLUE` lines pretty easily but what are the additional commands I need to find the immediately preceding `X:` per such instance, and pass the sorted result list to a `diff`? I haven't used command line intensively since AmiShell... sorry :-( Is there a cookbook for such use cases online?

Comment: Can you post some more of this text document, I don't seem to grasp it's format? Maybe you want `grep -A 1 Y:BLUE`?

Comment: Something like `grep -E "^X:|^Y:BLUE" | grep -B1 "^Y:BLUE" ` ?

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers your use cases so we can try to help you.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what Awk was designed for, though if speed is important, you'll want to use a database with an index.

Comment: @tripleee - no, speed is not of the essence. Just looking for a quick and clean way to treat highly structured data in a text file as if it were a DB for ad-hoc questioning

Comment: @KamilCuk - what is not clear?

Comment: The actual data you want to manipulate -- example input, expected output, clear boundary conditions, no hand-waving. Still possibly too broad if you have not attempted to solve it in code yourself.

Comment: Since I didn't have your expected output, I have provided a *prototype* of code that works fine but might not exactly fit your particular needs. You can however since I have added some explanations about it, use it as a base to build your own documents analyser.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider that you have the following 2 input documents:

```
$ more doc*
::::::::::::::
doc1
::::::::::::::
doc 1
  X:1
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:BLUE
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
  X:2
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:BLUE
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
  X:3
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:RED
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
  X:4
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:BLUE
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
::::::::::::::
doc2
::::::::::::::
doc 2
  X:4
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:BLUE
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
  X:3
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:BLUE
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
  X:2
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:RED
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
  X:1
#  more data pertaining to item 37
#  more data pertaining to item 37
  Y:BLUE
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
# more serialized data items including exactly 1 occurrence of "Y:" per   preceding "X:"
```

You can use the following `awk` command on each document to fetch the IDs:

```
$ awk -F':' '/X:[0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}/Y:BLUE$/{a[NR]=tmp}END{asort(a); for(i in a){print a[i]}}' doc1
1
2
4

$ awk -F':' '/X:[0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}/Y:BLUE$/{a[NR]=tmp}END{asort(a); for(i in a){print a[i]}}' doc2
1
3
4
```

**Explanations:**

- `-F':'` to define `:` as field separator:
- `/X:[0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}` will save in `tmp` variable the values of the ids (hypothesis the ids are composed only of digits and there is nothing else on the line), if this is not the case for you you can adapt the filtering regex `/X:[0-9]+$/` to fit your needs
- `/Y:BLUE$/{a[NR]=tmp}` when we reach a line with the pattern `Y:BLUE` (hypothesis: EOL just after `BLUE`) we add value saved in tmp to an array
- at the end of the processing we sort the array and print it, note that you change the `awk` command in `awk -F':' '/X:[0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}/Y:BLUE$/{print tmp}' | sort -n`

Then you can combine them in the following way to find the differences in term of blue ids between the 2 documents:

```
$ diff <(awk -F':' '/X:[0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}/Y:BLUE$/{a[NR]=tmp}END{asort(a); for(i in a){print a[i]}}' doc1) <(awk -F':' '/X:[0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}/Y:BLUE$/{a[NR]=tmp}END{asort(a); for(i in a){print a[i]}}' doc2)                                                    
2c2
< 2
---
> 3
```

or to find the blue ids in common between them:

```
$ comm -1 -2 <(awk -F':' '/X:[0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}/Y:BLUE$/{a[NR]=tmp}END{asort(a); for(i in a){print a[i]}}' doc1) <(awk -F':' '/X:[
0-9]+$/{tmp=$2}/Y:BLUE$/{a[NR]=tmp}END{asort(a); for(i in a){print a[i]}}' doc2)                                              
1
4
```